# Adding an accidently removed startup application

Tags: startup, cinnamon

I have accidentally removed "Cinnamon Settings Daemon - xrandr" from startup applications on my Linux Mint as I was trying to remove another application, but the topmost application was selected so this got removed.

How can I add it back, I think it may be an important startup app which I have accidentally removed

This is image with the setting present, but in my case this topmost option has been accidentally removed

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry simply runs the command `csd-xrandr`:

[image: screenshot of cinnamon settings showing the relevant command]

So, to add it again, just click on the "+" icon on the bottom of the settings screen:

[image: screenshot of cinnamon settings highlighting the plus icon]

And then enter the following values for each of the fields (so that it looks like in the first screenshot):

```
Name: Cinnamon Settings Daemon - xrandr
Command: csd-xrandr
Comment: No description
Startup delay: 0
```

Then, click "save" and you should be fine.